# Cassandra JMX Bean to monitor the hints

Tags: cassandra, jmx, datastax, opscenter, jolokia

Is there way to monitor the hints in cassandra cluster using the JMX Bean?

I am looking at : http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html#hintsservice-metrics and I see the below metric

```
Metric Name : org.apache.cassandra.metrics.HintedHandOffManager.<MetricName>
JMX MBean : org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=HintedHandOffManager name=<MetricName>
```

This is giving the cumulative count of the metrics, but I would like to have the time series trend of hints counts. is it possible to do it via JMX?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve this with JMX alone. Other tools/db will be required to store data periodically.

Currently, we are using prometheus + grafana for monitoring Cassandra performance. We have dashboard similar to [this](https://grafana.com/dashboards/371)

Comment: Yes, I am using grafana to store the metrics. but the problem here is, the JMX metrics only give the count of hints from the start/restart of the service. which is not the metric which can be consumable for to monitor. For example if I have 1000 hints now, the graph is always incrementally shows the count as 1000 or more but not zero after all the hints are replayed.

Comment: Also, I looked at the example grafana dashboard that you posted, it looks very cool. can you please share the JMXBeans that you are using to collect these metrics?

Comment: Sure, the dashboard I am using having two parts, first part is monitoring normal server load with node_exporter https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter. Second part is via JMX, which can be found here https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

Comment: Hello @Apolozeus , I tried several metrics for hints, but none of them seems to have correct point in time values. can you please share the JMX Bean name which you are using to collect the Hints metrics?

Comment: Yeah, i just cross check again. Surprisingly it seems like not all metrics mentioned in docs are available. I can only see two metrics `cassandra_storage_totalhints` and `cassandra_storage_totalhintsinprogress`. I am not sure if issue is with my prometheus exporter configuration or cassandra. However, there is a lot of metrics based on CF `hints`, you can cross check if some of them can be used. I will let you know if I can find anything as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried with all of the Hints metrics and none of them seems to be working for me. (may be I am doing something wrong which I can't figure out). it would be great if you can find the JMX Bean name and update here @Apolozeus